# Is there a package, perhaps a better way to resolve 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON' error?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a request to an api endpoint. However, I continue to receive a syntax error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON`

I have been trying to use every pointer on the web to no avail as the suggestions I have been getting doesn't quite relate to my issue. I was thinking maybe its how my payload is stored - "String": `<br /><br />1. The #StayAtHomePhotoChallenge: Participants take pictures of activities. <br /><br />2. ...` - Could this be the issue, is there a way to resolve this error so as to make a successful call to the api endpoint?

Here is a sample of my 'Response' via 'Network' tab in Chrome dev tool:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style data-next-hide-fouc="true">
    body {
      display: none
    }
  </style><noscript data-next-hide-fouc="true"><style>body{display:block}</style></noscript>
  <meta charSet="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <meta name="next-head-count" content="2" /><noscript data-n-css=""></noscript>
  <script defer="" nomodule="" src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills.js?ts=1678812948774"></script>
  <script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1678812948774" defer=""></script>
  <script src="/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1678812948774" defer=""></script>
  <script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1678812948774" defer=""></script>
  <script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/_error.js?ts=1678812948774" defer=""></script>
  <script src="/_next/static/development/_buildManifest.js?ts=1678812948774" defer=""></script>
  <script src="/_next/static/development/_ssgManifest.js?ts=1678812948774" defer=""></script><noscript id="__next_css__DO_NOT_USE__"></noscript></head>

<body>
  <div id="__next"></div>
  <script src="/_next/static/chunks/react-refresh.js?ts=1678812948774"></script>
  <script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json">
    {
      "props": {
        "pageProps": {
          "statusCode": 500
        }
      },
      "page": "/_error",
      "query": {
        "__NEXT_PAGE": "/api/pool-request.js"
      },
      "buildId": "development",
      "isFallback": false,
      "err": {
        "name": "Error",
        "source": "server",
        "message": "ENOTDIR: not a directory, access 'Path-to-my-file'",
        "stack": "Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, access "
      },
      "gip": true,
      "scriptLoader": []
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your endpoint is returning an html, most likely a "404 not found" page

Comment: I see. Any suggestion on how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it appears this is a 500 Server Error response.  In particular this is interesting `"message": "ENOTDIR: not a directory, access 'Path-to-my-file'",` Are you access the correct URL?  If so, maybe the application server logs can shed light on the exact reason for the 500 error.

```
{
      "props": {
        "pageProps": {
          "statusCode": 500
        }
      },
      "page": "/_error",
      "query": {
        "__NEXT_PAGE": "/api/pool-request.js"
      },
      "buildId": "development",
      "isFallback": false,
      "err": {
        "name": "Error",
        "source": "server",
        "message": "ENOTDIR: not a directory, access 'Path-to-my-file'",
        "stack": "Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, access "
      },
      "gip": true,
      "scriptLoader": []
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I somehow added the trailing '.js' in the url - good eye. Thanks again